# WebKit2Gtk WebView touchscreen scrolling

Tags: gtk3, webkit2

I've got kiosk web view on Raspberry PI with touch screen.
I can't figure out how get touch screen scroll working.
E.g. when i open chrome and navigate to website xyz, I can scroll using drag (pan?) gesture.
When I navigate to website xyz in my kiosk browser using WebKitWebView, I have to catch scrollbar and drag with him to scroll.

I tried google it, tried setting `gtk_scrolled_window_set_kinetic_scrolling`,  `"gtk-touchscreen-mode"`, using `GtkScrolledWindow` but still not lucky.
Maybe i am missing something...

Has anyone any hint for my solution?

Comment: I've found that `GtkGestures` should be used for this behavior, but I'm lost here, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, finally I've done simple scrolling, catching GtkGesture named "pan" and firing new scroll event in callback.